# how to use scp command?

Tags: file-transfer, scp

Is there any way of remembering how to use scp command?
I tend to forget how to use it. Folder/file argument - order of arguments etc.

Are there any tricks for remembering this, so that every-time i do not have to google it on how to use it.

Comment: what os? I'd recommend just using a gui of somesort if its a pain to remember. Or write, print and stick up a cheatsheet.

Comment: Use `man scp` when in doubt. With training, you'll learn. GUI is also a smart suggestion. Filezilla works on all the "usual" operating systems. But really: with repetition, the command syntax will stick, just like the multiplication table once upon a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just think of it exactly like `cp`: first you give the source, then you give the destination.
*Don't think of it as local and remote*, that's what trips most people up.
Extra options, if any come before anything.

The only extra wrinkle is that when either source or destination file is on a different computer, prefix it with `host:`. And of course, if it's not you, then do `user@host:`.